# is it possible to ensure the order when I add data?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In some cases, I want to copy some rows in the the same order that original rows. So I would like can order the original rows by ID and later create the new records in the same way.

But I don't know if EF ensure the order of the inserts or not, or if there are some kind of configuration that can ensure that.

One solution could be use a transactión, do a SaveChanges() after add the new row and finally commit the transaction. But I would like to avoid this because it would make me to use many SaveChanges() and also if for some reason the action can't be done because of some reason, the IDs that are assigned would be lose and I would have gaps. Really this second reason it is not important but I would like to avoid gaps if it is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your account has sufficient permissions:

```
ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TABLENAME] ON");
//do insert with original ids, meaning the primary key can't already exist in the target table
context.SaveChanges();
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TABLENAME] OFF");
```

Comment: In this solution, do I have to set the ID of the row manually? Because it is an autonumeric, assigned by the database.

Comment: yes, so you'd be overriding the target tables autonumeric function, so you would have a literal copy of the origin table.  Another option is the execute a stored proc to do the copy in order so you won't be calling savechanges several times.